# Colored text in a verbatimbox

Tags: floats, color, verbatim

I would like to have a block of verbatim text in a figure, small, centered, and blue.  By using the verbatimbox package I have managed to get three of four.  If, however, I use \color{blue} in the options to \begin{verbox}, the colour does not change.  If I place the command in the figure, only the first line changes, and the caption.  Any suggestions how I can get this to work?  I attach a small example file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}[\small\color{blue}]
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S
A 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
C 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
D 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
E 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
F 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
(stuff deleted)
attr(,"class")
[1] "mst"
\end{verbbox}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\theverbbox
\caption{Output from the \texttt{mst()} command.\label{MSTMat}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance, Kris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fancyvrb` instead:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{BVerbatim}[fontsize=\small,formatcom=\color{blue}]
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S
A 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
C 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
D 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
E 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
F 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
(stuff deleted)
attr(,"class")
[1] "mst"
\end{BVerbatim}
\caption{Output from the \texttt{mst()} command.\label{MSTMat}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant.  Exactly what I wanted!  Many thanks, Kris.